# AsyncImage refresh in kivy/python

Tags: python, kivy

In python2.7 + kivy1.9, I use AsyncImage like:

```
class Foo(BoxLayout):

..def bar(self):

....file_name=StringProperty()

..

..

....self.file_name="/../../image.png"

..
```

and in kivy,

```
BoxLayout:

..AsyncImage:

....source: root.file_name
```

Before the second call of function bar I change the content of image.png.
But the image displayed doesn't change.
I tried "nocache: True" after source command in kivy but it doesn't work.

How can I get the correct display everytime I call the func bar.

Comment: Can you make an example that is copy and pastable. You don't show where you call the function, nor where you change the image filename.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to post my sample program but rejected by formatting error (indent error?). I still continue to trying.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you declare `file_name` property in each `bar` call. The `file_name` property must be a class attribute:

**main.py**:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    image_path = StringProperty('image1.png')  # <<<<<<<<

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def change_image(self, path):
        self.image_path = path

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**test.kv:**

```
<RootWidget>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    AsyncImage:
        id: image
        source: root.image_path

    BoxLayout:  
        size_hint_y: 0.1

        Button:
            text: 'Image 1'
            on_press: root.change_image("image1.png")

        Button:
            text: 'Image 2'
            on_press: root.change_image("image2.png")
```

---

**EDIT**

---

If you would like to use only one file name and change the content of the image, you need call [`reload`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.reload) method (with `nocache` property `True`):

**main.py:**

```
import os
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.properties import  ObjectProperty


class AsyncTest(BoxLayout):
    img = ObjectProperty()

    def show_icon(self):
        self.img.source = "/sdcard/archive/icon_0.png"

    def switch(self):
        os.system("mv /sdcard/archive/icon_1.png /sdcard/archive/icon_0.png")
        self.img.reload()

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AsyncTest()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**test.ḱv:**

```
<AsyncTest>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    img: asyn_image

    AsyncImage:
        id: asyn_image
        nocache: True

    BoxLayout:

        size_hint_y: 0.1
        Button:
            text: 'Show'
            on_press: root.show_icon()

        Button:
            text: 'Switch'
            on_press: root.switch()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when I posted the question.

Comment: Original program is like:  class AsyncTest(BoxLayout): 
 icon_img=StringProperty()  def show_icon(self):   self.icon_img="/sdcard/archive/icon_0.png"   def switch(self):   os.system("mv /sdcard/archive/icon_1.png  /sdcard/archive/icon_0.png")

Comment: When two file names are different, like in your program, there's no problem.  In my application, I'd like to use only one file name and change the content of the image for some reason.

Comment: To simulate that situation, I define switch(self) function to "mv icon_1.png  icon_0.png" by pushing "switch" button, in sample program above.

Comment: @user9037109 check the edition (at the end of the answer).

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete program. It works perfectly.

Comment: And now I know I have to use ObjectProperty instead of StringProperty to reload.